# Passing parameter from Layout to activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm learning android development from Udacity [course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud836) created by google, in an exercise, it is asked to create a score record for two teams playing basketball. 
the app looks like :

[image].

You can guess what each button does .... 
To do that they create 6 methods (addThreePointToTeamA, addTwoPointToTeamA...) for each button. but I think that two methods (addTeamA, addTeamB) are enough if I could pass an int parameter correspond to the number of points to add to each method .

 So I wonder if it is possible to do that ? and if not, why ? 

Thank you in advance 

**EDIT**
here is what I wish to do : 
in the layout.xml :

```
    <Button
    ...
    android:text="+3 POINTS"
    android:onClick="addThreeTeamA(3)"
    />
```

then in the MainActivity.java:

```
public void addThreeTeamA(int point){
....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is technically possible to implement just only one Click Listener but not in the way you asked for since there is no a way to pass parameter to a click listener. Instead, you need to define `android:id` for every single button and use this approach.

```
public void buttonClicked(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnAddTeamAThree:
      // Add 3 points to Team A
      break;
    case R.id.btnAddTeamATwo:
      // Add 2 points to Team A
      break;
    case R.id.btnAddTeamBThree:
      // Add 3 points to Team B
      break;
    case R.id.btnAddTeamBTwo:
      // Add 2 points to Team B
      break;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for responding, that's a good solution, I thought of it but I wish to have something like in the **EDIT**

Comment: Actually there is also the another way which is to declare `android:tag` and read it as a parameter in the listener function through `v.getTag()`, for example, `<Button android:tag="3" android:onClick="buttonClicked" .../>`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple you can definitely do that.

I would say, think about your design though.

Here is what I would Recommend:

```
// Setup an interface for common team behaviors
interface Team {
   void addPoints(int points);
   int getPoints();
}

// implement that interface per Team
class TeamA implements Team {

    private int points;

    public TeamA(){
       this.points = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPoints(int points){
      this.points += points;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPoints(){
       return this.points;
    }

}
```

And do the same for TeamB!

then create a method in your Activity or whatever class your calling to add from:

```
public void addPoints(int points, Team team){
    team.addPoints(points);
}
```

Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Comment: thank you for your, comment, but I was thinking of passing parameter from the layout, see the edit

Comment: @aName thats not possible as an onClick from xml cannot handle args. and the listener needs to pass a single parameter a `View`

Comment: that's what I wanted to know. So the best solution to pass args **from layout to activity** is to use **Tag** as @nuuneoi said

Answer (score 0):

They created 6 methods for your better understanding. Once you get what they want to perform than you can enhance it. Yes you can enhance it by making generic methods for team-A and team-B. Its totally depend on your logic. Hope i answer your question.